# Overload return types?

Tags: c++

Lets say i have a class

```
Class rofl {
 int a;
 float b;
 rofl::rofl(int a, float b) {
  this->a = a; this->b = b;
 }
}
```

is it possible to do

```
rofl* sup = new rofl(5, 2.0f);
float hello = sup;
```

so that variable hello would get the value of sup.b?

Comment: This doesn't compile. The `Class` keyword shouldn't start with a capital letter, the `rofl::` qualification is unneccessary... I'm very tempted to downvote.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can overload *type-conversion operators*:

```
class Rofl {
public:
    operator float() const { return b; }

    ...
};
```

See http://ideone.com/Y7UwV for a demo.

However, see Item 5 of Scott Meyers' [*More Effective C++*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/More-Effective-Programs-Professional-Computing/dp/020163371X/), entitled "*Be wary of user-defined conversion operations*".  Allowing implicit conversions to-and-from complex types can often lead to all sorts of subtle typo bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go the other way around:

```
class rofl {
public:
    float operator=(float f) { b = f; return f; }

    ...
};

rofl sup(5, 2.0f);
sup = 4.0f;
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/049ee), based on [@Oli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177427/102441)

Answer (score 1):

No, in the case that you stated this is not possible.  In your code, `sup` is not a `rofl` but a `rofl*`, and creating a `rofl*` to `float` conversion is not allowed.  Moreover, your question is ill-formed: `sup.b` does not refer to anything.

That said, you probably don't need to dynamically allocate the instance, in which case the other answers are correct.